# Can I use RSpec to test deployed site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I should say first, that I'm not very well-versed in testing my code, and I didn't do it at all until recently.

So I have this rails app. It's basically an API endpoint. It takes requests and spits JSON. There's good (I hope) test coverage that should test most of the functionality.

Now we're deploying a staging env and want to let load testing guys (independent department) to "play" with it. I want to be super sure that we deployed it correctly.

Can I run RSpec's request specs against this staging deployment? Do people do this kind of testing at all? What are best practices? What should I read?

Comment: I can't see any added value to test the staging app. Only Travis executes my specs outside my computer. But you could do it using capybara.

Comment: It's another deployment, and I want to test overall behaviour of it. For example, I forgot to start my background workers. Now the system is not functioning correctly.

Comment: Sounds like you need to automate and test your deployment strategy.

Comment: Or maybe I should test that, yeah :)

Comment: There's this article on making capistrano run some specs for you, in your case you would do it for `RAILS_ENV=staging` instead of production, but there's nothing particularly special about any rails environment other than environment-specific settings, so you cna do it against any environment you set up if you wish. http://www.vaporbase.com/postings/Running_rspec_after_you_deploy

Comment: @DVG: thanks, I'm gonna try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can test deployed site using Rspec and Capybara. You need change configuration like this:

1. Change driver to `:webkit`, `:selenium` or `:poltergeist`, because the default driver (`:rack_test`) does not support running against a remote server.

   ```
   Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
   ```
2. Set app_host.

   ```
   Capybara.app_host = 'http://example.com'
   ```
3. Turn off local server.

   ```
   Capybara.run_server = false
   ```

After that you can create test for deployed server using Capybara DSL.

Comment: The site has no pages, no javascript. It's an API endpoint. It receives and sends JSON-formatted data. Does your answer still apply to this?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes. It still apply. And you can use capybara-mechanize driver.

Comment: Is there any solution without involving Capybara? Capybara is a perfect fit for user interface, but may be overkill for API endpoint where we don't need JavaScript, or even any analysis of HTML (so we don't need to pull in Nokogiri, for instance). I am thinking about RSpec just running the exact same test, only fetching the JSON with [`net/http`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) instead of the methods in [`ActionDispatch::Integration::RequestHelpers`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can run rspec without Rails and use the rest-client and json gems to test remote REST endpoints.

(I've used this method to produce readable tests for a Java application with a REST api.)