# Launch sinatra from a test/spec or another ruby script

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I'm experimenting, and I'm trying to launch dummy Sinatra application from RSpec and kill it when the spec is finished. Something like:

```
# spec/some_spec.rb

before(:all)
  # launch sinatra dummy app
end

after (:all)
  # kill sinatra dummy app
end

it 'should return list of whatever' do
  expect(JSON.parse(make_request('0.0.0.0:4567/test.json')))
   .to include('whatever')
end
```

I could use `system("ruby test/dummy/dummy_app.rb")`, but how can I kill that process only? Does anyone know how I can launch the Sinatra inside a test (or from another ruby script)? I know about WebMocks, but I want to see if I can manage to make my test work this way.

Answer (score 1):

Look under RSpec on "[Testing Sinatra with Rack::Test](http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html)". I'd suggest you use that code as boilerplate to get started.

Just add this to your describe block:

```
def app
  Sinatra::Application
end
```

I would suggest you read up RSpec.

---

Since you want to test an external system, by the looks of your comment, instead of `system "curl whatewer.com"`, you can use Net::HTTP to make requests and then test against the response.

Have a look at "[Testing an external API using RSpec's request specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364076/testing-an-external-api-using-rspecs-request-specs)".

Comment: thank you for the link to sinatra RSpec section, I red it before but I didn't realize it then that I can use it the way I want use it.

Comment: Hi sorry I accepted you answer, but I discovered it's not fully fulfilling my needs. What I'm writing is more of a smoke test upon which I need to make actual request to some actual live server. I'm re-factoring a legacy code where in lot of places they are using `system "curl whatewer.com"` I want to refactor that, first I need to make sure I wont break existing stuff.  However this is good spot(so +1).

Comment: Made an update to the answer for what I think you want to do.

Comment: Hi, I agree with you on the update, but like I said before re-factoring the system `curl` to ruby `net-http` or `party_foul`

Answer (score 0):

As I'm writing request specs to ensure the features won't be broken I decided to rather write separate Cucumber features. The nice thing is that I can use Capybara, and thanks to Selenium Web Drive, I can launch a server before I run my tests.

So, I created a dummy Sinatra application (that will represent the external service to which the actual code I'm testing is doing requests (including a nasty `system('curl whatever.com')`).

All I have to do is stub out the methods passed to curl to use `Capybara.current_session.server.host` and `Capybara.current_session.server.port`.

Once I'm done with my re-factoring all I have to do is remove the Capybara server variables, and Selenium web drive from the cucumber/capybara configuration.

Tests after a brief change will be still working and will be valid.

**Update**

In the end I wrote it all with RSpec request tests, as doing it in Cucumber was little bit time consuming and I already spend too much time on this.

I mark these kind of request tests with RSpec tag and Before I lunch these I manually lunch simple Sinatra/Grape dummy API application to which the request are made. (Then I run RSpec tests with this tag)

So basically I end up with specs for functionality that uses net/http that uses WebMock and don't need a server, and request tests for which I need to run the server before I run the specs.  **So the original question remains, how to lunch a server before tests start**

After I cover all the functionality I'm gonig to rewrite the curl to net/http however I'm going to keep those requests specs as I discovered they are nice idea when it comes to crazy API scenarios (like testing https + diggested authentication)